# In electromagnetic inductance, which one is more efficient, to focus all power to move one part or split it to move both at the same time?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetics, induction

Assuming equal force is used, which one would be more efficient when it comes to generating current through electromagnetic induction: to use 100% of available force to move the permanent magnet only or the coil only? Or to use 50% to move the magnet and 50% to move the coil? My thinking is that speed plays an important role so I thought by moving both it will improve the efficiency by increasing the cutting speed of the magnetic flux. Thank you.

Comment: This is more of a physics question, I'm not sure it is a good fit here.

Answer (score 3):

I think you could do with reasoning just a little more abstractly.

Consider the magnet-coil system.

If you move them with a speed relative to each other, you will generate a voltage.
If the coil carries a current, this will create a force between them.

On the electrical side, current x volts = power.
On the mechanical side, force x speed = power.

These are all speeds and forces of the coil and magnet **relative to each other**. It does not matter which one you choose to take as the origin of your coordinates, so regard to be 'fixed', or even whether you take the centre of mass as the origin, you get exactly the same force/speed/volts/current/power sums.

In practice, due to mechanical reasons, it may be more convenient to move the magnet, or the coil. The magnets might be heavy and fragile, so limit how fast you can spin them before they fall apart. If you move the coil, you may need flexible or even sliding electrical connections. Or you may have raided your junk box and fished out some parts that suggest they get moved this or that way.

It doesn't matter electrically, or for the conservation of energy. If you want to generate 10 watts, you need to supply a total of 10 watts+losses mechanically to one or both elements.